# Discord.py - Optional Args

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having trouble setting up a command with an optional Arg to reload my cogs. It was telling me the command didn't exist and after some modifications it was reloading all of the arguments even when I use an arg for a specific cog. Currently it's trying to reload a cog called None.

My Code:

```
@commands.has_role("Founder")
@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension=None):
    if  ctx.channel.name == ("dev-testing") and {extension} == None:
        for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
            if filename.endswith('.py'):
                bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
                bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
                await ctx.send("All cogs have been reloaded!")
                print(bcolors.WARNING + "All cogs have been reloaded!" + bcolors.ENDC)
        

    elif ctx.channel.name == ("dev-testing") and {extension} != None:
            bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
            await ctx.send(f'{extension} has been reloaded!')
            print(bcolors.WARNING + f'{extension} has been reloaded!' + bcolors.ENDC)
```

And this is the error I get when I don't specify an arg.

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotLoaded: Extension 'cogs.None' has not been loaded.
```

I have made multiple modifications to this trying to get it to work and it's still trying to load the default value for the arg. I even tried without a default value, I tried with NULL, I tried all kinds of things but can't seem to get this working properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you comparing it like this?

```py
if {extension} != None:
```

When putting it inside the curly brackets you're casting it to a set, a set is never `None`, simply do:

```py
if extension is not None:
```

Comment: I didn't know that using the curly brackets was casting to a set. After a lot of google searching looking for an answer and trying to find a solution I couldn't find anything that worked so I decided to keep trying on my own and the code I posted was the last revision I had before asking here for guidance. I tried removing the brackets and it's reloading all of the cogs but not specific ones anymore but doesn't throw an stderror in console anymore either.

Comment: That's weird, can you maybe try adding a print right after the `elif` statement?

Comment: That was my mistake on the placement of `not` in the `if elif` statements. Everything seems to be working properly now. Thank you! I'm going to look more into the casting of sets in python so I can get a better understanding of how that works.

Comment: There are sets and dicts that are represented with the same curly braces, the difference is that a dict is a key-value pair, i.e `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}`. a set it's just an unordered and unindexed list `{'value1', 'value2'}`